# Cant get data from Windows forms DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, outlook, vsto

I am using DataGridView in VSTO outlook plugin with windows forms. I implemented data from .csv in to the grid. Now I would like to filter data fith textbox.  I have a code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Form1 frm in System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms)
            {
                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = frm.DataGrid.DataSource;
               
                bs.Filter = DataGrid.Columns[0].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + searchtextBox.Text + "%'";
                DataGrid.DataSource = bs;
 //  File.AppendAllText(@"C:\install\CSharp\tulemus.txt", $"The grid is: {frm.DataGrid.DataSource}" + Environment.NewLine);   checking the source and it is null. Why?
            }
            
        }
```

The problem is that

> frm.DataGrid.DataSource

Doesenent take datagrid value. I dont understand how I should get the Datasource. My DataGrid gets values each time I start it from csv file with foreach sicle.

Adding info. I am implementig data from csv making list like this:

```
foreach (Form1 frm in System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms)
            {
              
                var csvTable = new DataTable();
                using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead($@"{AppdtataMallid}\{selectedFile}")), true))
                {
                    csvTable.Load(csvReader);
                }
                

                
                List<SearchParameters> searchParameters = new List<SearchParameters>();
                for (int i = 0; i < csvTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    searchParameters.Add(new SearchParameters { Eesnimi = csvTable.Rows[i][0].ToString(), Perenimi = csvTable.Rows[i][1].ToString(), Isikukood = csvTable.Rows[i][2].ToString() });

                }
               
                foreach (var searchparameter in searchParameters)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)frm.DataGrid.Rows[j].Clone();
                    row.Cells[0].Value = j+1;
                    row.Cells[1].Value = searchparameter.Eesnimi;
                    row.Cells[1].Value += " ";
                    row.Cells[1].Value += searchparameter.Perenimi;
                    row.Cells[2].Value = searchparameter.Isikukood;
                    frm.DataGrid.Rows.Add(row);
                    j++;
                }

            }
```

I figured out how to do this. Maby it is not fastest way but here it is:

```
foreach (Form1 frm in System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms)
            {

                CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[frm.DataGrid.DataSource];
                currencyManager.SuspendBinding();

                // Show all lines
                for (int u = 0; u < frm.DataGrid.RowCount; u++)
                {
                    frm.DataGrid.Rows[u].Visible = true;
                    
                }

                //   Hide the ones that you want with the filter you want.
                for (int u = 0; u < frm.DataGrid.RowCount; u++)
                {

                    if (frm.DataGrid.Rows[u].Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(frm.searchtextBox.Text.ToString().ToUpper()))
                    {
                        frm.DataGrid.Rows[u].Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        frm.DataGrid.Rows[u].Visible = false;
                    }
                }

                // Resume data grid view binding
                currencyManager.ResumeBinding();
            }
```

Yes it is working as I changed some logic as I have been suggested down below.

```
List<SearchParameters> searchParameters = new List<SearchParameters>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < csvTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        searchParameters.Add(new SearchParameters { Nimi = csvTable.Rows[i][0].ToString() + " " + csvTable.Rows[i][1].ToString(), Isikukood = csvTable.Rows[i][2].ToString(), Büroo = csvTable.Rows[i][3].ToString() });

                    }


                    frm.DataGrid.DataSource = searchParameters;
```

Comment: You are going to have to provide more info. Your comment… _”I implemented data from .csv in to the grid.”_ … “how” did you do this? Did you manually set each cell, make a `DataTable` or a `List<T>` and use it as a data source?

Comment: The code “implies” the grid has a `DataSource`… `bs.DataSource = frm.DataGrid.DataSource;` … however, unless there is a “global” variable holding the “original” data source, the code is going to “lose” this data on the line… `DataGrid.DataSource = bs;` … this effectively “looses” any connection to the original data after the filter is applied. Which means you would need to re-read the csv each time a filter is applied.

Comment: Hello. I updated my post. I am making list and then setting each cell. So as I understood I cant use data from my Datagrid and I need to make new list like I did at first from CSV and use it? I will try to do so.

Comment: The code appears to be adding the data to the grid “manually” cell by cell. Because of this the grid does NOT use/have a `DataSource`. Therefore, the line in the filter code… `bs.DataSource = frm.DataGrid.DataSource;` is going to return “empty” or null since the grids data source was never set. It’s not surprising that the grid is empty after …. `DataGrid.DataSource = bs;`. I suggest some research on setting the grids data source to something like a `DataTable`. Manually adding the data will make the sorting more difficult.

Comment: Your solution will work, however, there are easier ways to do this if the grid had a `DataSource`. In your solution, I question the use of the `CurrencyManager` as it appears to do nothing! As stated previously the line… `CurrencyManager currencyManager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[frm.DataGrid.DataSource];` … is going to be null or empty because the `frm.DataGrid.DataSource` is empty or null since you have NOT set the grids `DataSource`.

Comment: Yes it is working as I changed some logic as you suggested. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `DataTable table` object as a private field. All data binding to this `table` object. Replace your `frm.DataGrid.DataSource` with `table`.

`frm.DataGrid` looks like ASP.NET Webform's `GridView`. It's datasource can not be loaded when postback to click event(or other event).